# How to use single quotation marks inside a xpath expression in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I need to search the website for a button with a name that might contain a apostrophe and I don't know how to do it.

```
a = "Ming'an Cui"
n = "55"
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(span,'"+a+"')]/span[@class='btn-subtext' and contains(text(),"+n+")]").click()
```

Then i get this message:

> InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression "//button[contains(span,'Ming'an Cui')]/span[contains(span,'Ming'an Cui')]" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

Comment: can u provide html example of that button?

Comment: <button class=""><span class="btn-text">Cui Ming'an</span><span class="btn-subtext">55</span></button>

Comment: //button/span[@class='btn-subtext' and contains(text(),"+n+")]

Comment: Thanks, but there are multiple buttons with the same number.

Comment: //button[span[text()='name here'] and span[text()='number here']]
try this, replacing name and numbers with your values

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use `escape sequence character` before it that is `back slash (\)`
some thing like mentioned below

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(span,'"+"Ming\'an Cui"+"')]/span[@class='btn-subtext' and contains(text(),"+n+")]").click()
```

Comment: InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression "//button[contains(span,'Ming'an Cui')]/span[@class='btn-subtext' and contains(text(),55)]" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(span,\"'+a+'\")]/span[@class="btn-subtext" and contains(text(),"55")]').click()#nomes
```

fixed it :D